# Errors Saving Entries

Tags: entries, error-message, saving

Suddenly getting errors when trying to save entries.
Have recently upgraded to latest version of Craft.

When I try up update a Single Entry I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributes() on a non-object in /path-to-site/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php on line 484
```

When a try to save a Channel in IE11 it pops up - Do you want to open or save - 210-a-new-news-articlef93bf125.json(1.09KB) from domainname.com

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something may be corrupt in your `/app` folder... I'd recommend performing a [manual update](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/329/45) to try to fix the problem.

If you are still experiencing this issue after performing the manual update, I'd recommend contacting Pixel & Tonic directly, to report this as a bug.

You can email them at support@buildwithcraft.com, or use the "Send a message to Craft Support" widget on your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks - have tried this - but still getting the error. Have contacted Pixel & Tonic

Comment: Got reply from Brad through the support. Issues was resolved by this: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/forms-returning-json

Comment: Never would have guessed that. Glad you got it sorted!