# Table 'craft.craft_elementindexsettings' doesn't exist

Tags: database, auto-updates, manual-updates

I have a local site that was running perfectly, but last year when I ran the auto-update it seems that it did not finish the process. At that time didn't have time to have a look to what happened (please bear in mind I'm a designer, and this is not a client site :D), and yesterday I saw that the admin dashboard was not working, and some pages were not loading too.

I downloaded the files again from the website, replaced the craft/app folder following the manual update instructions, and all seem to be fine (site works and dashboard works), except that when I go to entries I get this error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or > view not found: 1146 Table 'craft.craft_elementindexsettings' doesn't exist

Other pages of the admin side works fine, I've cleared the cache and that made no difference.

When I uploaded the new craft/new and went to /admin, I did not get any message about updating the database as the instructions say.

I also can't recall why the auto-update didn't work properly. I kind of remember that the page got stuck, or I got an error, but as the internet in this office is quite bad, I thought the problem was at my end, not craft.

Any ideas on how to solve it? 
Is it possible to re-run the auto-update of the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has actually come up before in the Slack channel...

> "That’s a brand new Craft 2.5 table, so you’ve probably tried to do the update before, it failed and you didn’t clear out all tables from the database when you retried." - Brad Bell

As you mentioned, your auto-update did not complete successfully. So the logical next step (as you tried) is to perform a [manual update](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/329/how-can-i-manually-update-craft).

But here's the catch... Before you made your 2nd (manual) attempt, **you didn't roll back your database**. Between attempts, you would need to *drop all tables* and re-import your original database SQL file.

Comment: I dropped all the tables and re-import my latest SQL file. Craft asked me to update the database and did not return any error. But now when adding a new entry I get this error:

Internal Server Error
Craft\EntryElementType and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "defineTableAttributes".

Comment: Sounds like your `app` folder might be corrupt. Try replacing it with a fresh copy.

Comment: Seemed to be the problem, finally managed to install an old 2.4.x version to leave it working in a pre-update way. Thanks!